# Javascript FileReader

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
 <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
<output id="list"></output>

<script>
  function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

    // files is a FileList of File objects. List some properties.
    var output = [];
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
      output.push('<li><strong>', escape(f.name), '</strong> (', f.type || 'n/a', ') - ',
                  f.size, ' bytes, last modified: ',
                  f.lastModifiedDate.toLocaleDateString(), '</li>');
    }
    document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = '<ul>' + output.join('') + '</ul>';
  }

  document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
</script>
```

Consigo los datos del archivo leído. 
Como leo el contenido y se lo asigno a una variable ?

No consigo entender la API FileReader

Comment: ¿Cuál es el objetivo de usar FileReader en este caso? El siguente [enlace](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/tutorials/determine-an-images-type-using-the-javascript-filereader.html#fbid=SYgE4OMKEDq) muestra un ejemplo usando FileReader para obtener el tipo MIME de una imagen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este ejemplo pones solo extraer la información del archivo, es decir, la metadata. De hecho no utilizas [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/FileReader) solo File.

Te recomiendo leer el [API oficial del w3](https://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-load-event)

Y puedes revisar la funcionalidad en [este  jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bgrins/7DjCP/) (Yo no lo he creado), **en la prueba puedes subir un archivo de texto y ver el contenido en el navegador**, que es lo que quieres.

El truco principal es preguntar si esta soportado el API y de ahí ejecutar el proceso Asíncrono.

Answer (score 3):

Lo que te falta es muy sencillo: definir lectores para los ficheros, y asignar la acción que se ejecutará cuando se cargue:

```
  function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object
    var lectores = new Array(); // los lectores

    // files is a FileList of File objects. List some properties.
    var output = [];
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
      output.push('<li><strong>', escape(f.name), '</strong> (', f.type || 'n/a', ') - ',
                  f.size, ' bytes, last modified: ',
                  f.lastModifiedDate.toLocaleDateString(), '</li>');


        // creas un lector para cada fichero o podría haber problemas
        lectores[i] = new FileReader(); 

        // define qué quieres que ocurra cuando se cargue el contenido
        lectores[i].onload = function(e) {
            var contenido = this.result;
            console.log(contenido); // mostrar por la consola
        }

        // leer cada fichero como texto (esto se ejecuta de manera asíncrona)
        lectores[i].readAsText(f);
    }
    document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = '<ul>' + output.join('') + '</ul>';
  }

  document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

Es importante tener en cuenta que la carga se hace de forma asíncrona (el código continuará su ejecución normal y el `onload` no se ejecutará hasta que el fichero se cargue).

También es importante utilizar un lector diferente para cada fichero. Si utilizas el mismo, podría haber un conflicto y fallaría el script (o el resultado podría no ser el esperado).

---

Aquí dejo una demo con el código (mira la consola para ver el contenido de los ficheros, si eliges un fichero muy pesado puede tardar en mostrarse el contenido):

```js
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
  var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object
  var lectores = new Array();

  // files is a FileList of File objects. List some properties.
  var output = [];
  for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
    output.push('<li><strong>', escape(f.name), '</strong> (', f.type || 'n/a', ') - ',
                f.size, ' bytes, last modified: ',
                f.lastModifiedDate.toLocaleDateString(), '</li>');


    lectores[i] = new FileReader();

    lectores[i].onload = function(e) {
      var contenido = this.result;
      console.log(contenido);
    }

    lectores[i].readAsText(f);
  }
  document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = '<ul>' + output.join('') + '</ul>';
}

document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

```html
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
<output id="list"></output>
```

Comment: Entendido. Gracias a todos