# ¿Cómo mantener el fichero tras un reload?

Tags: javascript

Tengo un campo `input file` como el de la imagen.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<td width="43%" colspan="3">Adjuntar un archivo:<input tabindex="-1" class="fileObligatorio" id="ControlAnexar0" style="width: 100%;"  type="file">
  <input type="button" onClick="location.reload()" value ="Reload">
```

Tras un `location.reload()` de la página, el fichero seleccionado se pierde y has de seleccionarlo de nuevo.

Hay algún modo de **guardar ese fichero en una variable** en Javascript para poder cargarlo de nuevo tras un `reload`?

Temo que por seguridad esto no se pueda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como dice [Garrizano en su respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/39351/250), por motivos de seguridad no se puede mantener el fichero seleccionado en el `input type="file"`, pero sí hay maneras de mantener el fichero cuando se recargue la página.

La idea sería usar la [API FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/FileReader) para leer el contenido del fichero y guardarlo en memoria para poder usarlo después de que se recargue la página (puedes ver un ejemplo de como leer el contenido usando FileReader en otra [respuesta que escribí sobre el tema](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/4785/250)).

Entonces lo que tendrías que hacer es lo siguiente:

1. En cuanto el usuario seleccione un fichero, lee su contenido con FileReader
2. Guarda el contenido en el `localStorage` (o `sessionStorage`)
3. Cuando la página se recargue, comprueba si tienes un fichero en el `localStorage`
4. Si lo tienes, muestra un enlace indicando que el usuario ya subió un fichero (pon el nombre)
5. Deja el `input type="file"` vacío (por si el usuario quiere cambiar el fichero).

Aquí dejo un ejemplo de cómo se podría ver el código:

```
<div id="nombrefichero"></div>
<div>
Adjuntar un archivo:<input tabindex="-1" class="fileObligatorio" id="ControlAnexar0" style="width: 100%;"  type="file">
</div>
<input type="button" onClick="location.reload()" value ="Reload">
<script>

function ficheroCargado(nombre, contenido) {

    // mostramos los valores
    document.getElementById("nombrefichero").innerHTML = "Fichero cargado: " + nombre;
    console.log(contenido);

    // guardamos los valores en el localStorage
    localStorage.setItem("nombre", nombre);
    localStorage.setItem("contenido", contenido);

}

function leerFichero(evt) {
    var file = evt.target.files[0]; // FileList object
    var lector = new FileReader();

    lector.onload = function(e) {
        ficheroCargado(file.name, this.result);
    }

    lector.readAsText(file);
}

document.getElementById('ControlAnexar0').addEventListener('change', leerFichero, false);

if (localStorage.getItem("nombre") && localStorage.getItem("contenido")) {
    ficheroCargado(localStorage.getItem("nombre"), localStorage.getItem("contenido"));
} 
</script>
```

---

Ten en cuenta que esta solución tiene algunas limitaciones:

- el fichero debe ser menor que el tamaño permitido en el `localStorage` (o podrías usar algún otro método para almacenarlo),
- las cookies deben estar activadas,
- y el archivo debe leerse antes de recargar la página (ten en cuenta que la lectura es asíncrona)

Comment: muchas gracias! muy completo. Ahora queda más como puro conocimiento ya que me han dicho que quite el `reload`. Pa la próx ya se. ^^

Comment: @lois6b añadí un pequeño ejemplo que podrías usar como guía

Comment: si, lo acabo de ver. la guinda del pastel. gracias de nuevo

Answer (score 3):

Así como tú dices, por razones de seguridad no es posible realizar lo que deseas.

[Aquí hay más información](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/file.html#value) acerca de este comportamiento del navegador.

Comment: muchas gracias por la información ^^